# Filter all rows having all their numbers existing in another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Having a matrix `A` like:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
  [1,]   11   14   17   20   23   26    7    1   10     4    21     3
  [2,]   12   15    8   21   14   27   17   11   19     2     1     3
  [3,]   13   16   19   22   25   28    7   11   10     5    10     4
  [4,]   11   15   28   21    4   27    7    1   12    20    12    23
  [5,]   14   16    9   22   25   28    7    1   13    21    29     3
  [6,]   11    3    6   23   24   26    7    1   14    12    20     4
```

and a matrix `B` like:

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] ,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] 
 [1,]     2   17   10    4    5    6    7    1    21    20    23    24    11  14     3    26    12    10
```

I want to get only the rows that have all their values existing in matrix `B`.
   The result should be:

```
  [1] TRUE
  [2] FALSE
  [3] FALSE
  [4] FALSE
  [5] FALSE
  [6] TRUE
```

Is there an R function I can use to solve it?

Comment: Can we also filter all rows of matrix A that contain exactly any 3 numbers of matrix B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
apply(A,1,function(x) all(x %in% B))
```

Or vectorized:

```
rowSums(matrix(A %in% B, ncol = ncol(A)))==ncol(A)
```